# How to create groups like that in buddypress?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, categories, taxonomy, buddypress

I want to create a plugin where users can create group and add members to that group.. just like that in buddypress.. I dont want to use buddypress because I want to learn how to do it..

Please instruct me (code not required)..

How i did this is by creating a post type called "Groups" then After clicking "Add new" button I thought of adding a new group..  But The actually Admin page of Buddypress looked very different from mines as there were no buttons like "Add new" and there were members inside that group..

Thank you..

Comment: [Roles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) is probably what you're thinking of.

Comment: I dont think Roles will help me..  @NathanJohnson